# Getting "TypeError: "_Ctor" is read-only" when using import for a component in a Vue + .Net core app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core

I'm a bit of a newbie with Vue (v2) and am trying to integrate it into a .net core mvc application. Essentially, I am planning on only using it on one or two pages but will have a number of nested components.

My problem (I think) is that I'm not using webpack and am just using .js files for the components. To do this, I'm trying to import the components as required. When I got started, I was just using script tags to bring in components as none were nested. However, I'm now finding the need to get the imports working and am having a problem which I can't seem to resolve.

My page looks as such (Simplified):

```
<div id="app" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>

<script type="module">
    import * as ComponentContainer from '@Href("~/js/components/ComponentContainer.js")';
    
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: function () {
            return {
                bComponents: [ 
                    {
                        type: 'Type A',
                        sortOrder: 1,
                        uniqueId: 'ABCDEF'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'Type B',
                        sortOrder: 3,
                        uniqueId: '123456'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'Type A',
                        sortOrder: 2,
                        uniqueId: 'QWERTY'
                    }
                ],
                editMode: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            componentMethod(selectorId) {
                console.log(selectorId);
            },
        },
        computed: {
            sortedBComponents: function () {
                return this.bComponents.sort((a, b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder);
            }
        },
        components: {
            'component-container': ComponentContainer
        },
        template: `
            <div>
                <component-container v-for="comp in sortedBComponents"
                    :key="comp.uniqueId"
                    :componentData="comp"
                    :editMode="editMode"
                    @@component-method="componentMethod">
                </component-container>
            </div>
        `
    });
</script>
```

The component (component-container) has the following code:

```
export { ComponentContainer }

var ComponentContainer = {
    props: ['componentData', 'editMode'],
    mounted: function() {
        
    },
    methods: {
        componentSelected() {
            this.$emit('component-method', this.componentData.uniqueId);
        }
    },
    components: {
        
    },
    template: `
        <div :id="componentData.uniqueId + '-contianer'">
            {{componentData.type}}, {{componentData.sortOrder}} & {{componentData.uniqueId}}
            <a type="button" @click="componentSelected">Test</a>
        </div>
    `
}
```

This worked when the component was referenced via the script tag, but since trying to get it to work with the 'import' method, it appears to fail in a way were I can't figure out what's happening.

I get the following error in the conosle:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: "_Ctor" is read-only"
(found in <Root>)
```

And:

```
TypeError: "_Ctor" is read-only
```

I can't seem to figure out what this refers to. I know that the ComponentContainer is being loaded as I can write it to the console but maybe it's not loading in correctly. It works if I bring in the component through a script tag, but not through the import method.

Many thanks in advance for looking at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { ComponentContainer } from '/js/components/ComponentContainer.js';
```